# Use nested for loops to go through columns and rows in a matrix?

Tags: matlab

I have some code that is supposed to go through rows 50 to 90 and columns 40 to 80 and then change all numbers that are greater than 8 to 8.
This is my code

```
for i = 50:90
   for j = 40:80
    if (x(i,j) > 8)
        x(x>8)=8;
    end

end end
```

I have to use nestled loops but my code also changes numbers outside the chosen columns and rows. What have I done wrong?

Comment: change `x(x>8)=8;` to `x(i,j)=8;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

shouldn't the `if` statement be:

```
if (x(i,j) > 8)
    x(i,j) = 8
end
```